# COUNTIF Partial Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am working on a password audit, and one of the tasks I'm trying to solve is counting the number of instances a username is present in the password.  For instance, the username might be 'mikeb' and their password is 'mikeb123'.

Searching for a username in a password is simple enough: COUNTIF(A:A, "mikeb")

The problem I'm running into is how to I check A1 against B1, A2 against B2, for the entire column, and add up the number of times that B contained A.

Currently I'm using a workaround where I make the comparison then count the number of true values in a separate column.  I'd like to get away from another column if possible.

EDIT: Per request, dummy data:

```
Username    Password              Password Contains Username?
Bob         BobHasASneakyPa$$word TRUE
Carol       No1LikesUCarol        TRUE
Admin       <>@@Admin@@<>         TRUE
Brian       ;Ui6$m8/4??k3&)r7     FALSE
```

This is what my data looks like right now.  I am using **COUNTIF(A2, "*" & B2 & "*")>0** for the third column, then doing **COUNTIF(C:C, "TRUE")** to count up the # of times this happens.  Ideally I'd combine these into one equation.

Comment: Some dummy data will help us

Comment: Just hide your third column and pretend it's not there

Comment: Heh, that's what I'm doing right now.  Anything that takes two steps though, I see if it can be done in one.

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2:A5,B2:B5)))
```

I've tested this on your dummy data and searched for the username in the password. It returns an answer of 3 which would be the same as summing your third column.

You could also make this case sensitive if needs be by changing `SEARCH` to `FIND`

Comment: Works!  Thanks for the help!